# AngularJS $routeProvider does not have reload method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

The AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route#methods) indicates that the `ngRoute` `$routeProvider` has a `reload` method.

> **reload()**
>
> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location
>   hasn't changed.

As can be seen in this screen shot, the `$routeProvider` does not have a `reload` method.

[image: log of actual $route methods]

I am initializing my module like this:

```
var pageApp = angular.module('pageApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

and I am requesting the `$resourceProvider` like this:

```
pageApp.config([
    '$controllerProvider',
    '$compileProvider',
    '$filterProvider',
    '$routeProvider',
    '$provide',
    function($controllerProvider, 
            $compileProvider, 
            $filterProvider, 
            $routeProvider, 
            $provide) { 
        //generate attached screenshot output
        console.log($routeProvider);
        /* ... */ 
     }]);
```

I am using version 1.2.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `reload` method belongs to the `$route` service, not the `$routeProvider` provider.

i.e. you would use that methoid inside a controller, not the config function

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$route', function($route){

    $scope.reloadPage=$route.reload();

}]);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory if you're confused about the difference between services and providers. In this case. we have the $route service and the $routeProvider provider.